# Troubles getting boost::logger to compile

Tags: c++, logging, boost, cmake

I'm struggling with getting some `boost::logging` demo application running. I've got the following:
`logger.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;


void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log("sample.log");

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (   
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}

int main(void) {
    init();

    std::cout <<"Hello World!";
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(LOGGER)

set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/path/to/env/include")
set(BOOST_ROOT "/path/to/env/include")

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

message(STATUS Boost_LIBRARIES:)
message (STATUS ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
message(STATUS BOOST_INCLUDEDIR:)
message(STATUS ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(logger logger.cpp)
target_include_directories(logger PUBLIC ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})

target_link_libraries(logger Boost::boost ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")
```

and on `make` I get this:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target logger
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/logger.dir/logger.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable logger
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lBoost::boost
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/logger.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'logger' failed
make[2]: *** [logger] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/logger.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/logger.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and I don't understand why! 
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: According to [the `add_file_log` reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/add_file_log.html) you need to include `<boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>`. Perhaps try that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hoops, sounds right, Thanks! I've updated the question - I've now got a problem with the library that it can't find... hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem was because you didn't include the correct header file. For [`add_file_log`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/add_file_log.html) the `<boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>` header file is needed.

For the second problem (which should really be a second question, no one likes a moving target), if you read [the `FindBoost` reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) you will see that

> ```
> Boost::boost                Target for header-only dependencies
>                             (Boost include directory)
> ```

That's not the libraries you need to link with. Remove it from the `target_link_libraries` command.